# How can I prevent net::ERR_INSUFICIENT_RESOURCES errors caused by ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, electron

Yes, I have a performance problem, `ng-repeat` is too fast!

I'm using angular with electron and I am loading `img` tags (thumbnails ~ 10kb) inside an `ng-repeat`. If I have over ~600 of them, I get `net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES` errors from webkit:

```
<div ng-repeat="photo in photoImport.data">
  <img ng-src="{{photo.thumbnail}}" alt="">
</div>
```

How can I best slow `ng-repeat` down to (or otherwise prevent) network errors due to too many requests?

Additionally, note the intended behaviour is that all the photo's in the list load *as fast as possible* - the user should be able to jump to the last thumbnail in the list as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

One answer is to use the `limitTo` filter combined with an interval:

```
<div ng-repeat="photo in photoImport.data | limitTo : ngRepeatLimit>
```

with the following in the controller:

```
  function ngRepeatAllSlowly(photoImport) {
    let incr = 400,
        cycleCount = Math.ceil(photoImport.length / incr),
        stop;

      // Set initial limit
      $scope.ngRepeatLimit = 20;

      // Then reguarly increase it.
      stop = $interval(incrementLimit, incr, cycleCount, true).then(function(){
         $interval.cancel(stop);
      });

      // Increase ngRepeatLimit
      function incrementLimit() {
        $scope.ngRepeatLimit += incr;
      }
  }

  ngRepeatAllSlowly($scope.photoImport)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using lazy loading approach, something like code below. So that images get loaded only once user scrolls to them :

```html
   <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="Demo" ng-controller="AppController">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />

 <title>
  Lazy Loading Images With AngularJS
 </title>

 <style type="text/css">

  /* Add "click" styles because newer releases of AngularJS don't seem to add the HREF value. */
  a[ ng-click ] {
   cursor: pointer ;
   text-decoration: underline ;
  }

  a.box {
   background-color: #FAFAFA ;
   border: 1px solid #CCCCCC ;
   display: block ;
   height: 200px ;
   line-height: 200px ;
   text-align: center ;
   width: 684px ;
  }

  ul.photos {
   list-style-type: none ;
   margin: 16px 0px 16px 0px ;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px ;
   width: 700px ;
  }

  ul.photos:after {
   content: "" ;
   clear: both ;
   display: block ;
   height: 0px ;
  }

  li.photo {
   background-color: #FAFAFA ;
   border: 1px solid #CCCCCC ;
   border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px ;
   float: left ;
   margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px ;
   padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px ;
  }

  li.photo img {
   border: 1px solid #EEEEEE ;
   border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px ;
   display: block ;
  }

  img[ bn-lazy-src ] {
   background-image: url( "./checkered.png" ) ;
  }

 </style>
</head>
<body>

 <h1>
  Lazy Loading Images With AngularJS
 </h1>

 <p>
  You have {{ photos.size }} photos in your set.

  <a ng-click="rebuildSet()">Rebuild set</a>.
  <a ng-click="changeSource()">Change src</a>.
  <a ng-click="clearPhotos()">Clear</a>.
 </p>

 <a ng-show="isBoxVisible" ng-click="hideBox()" class="box">
  This is a big thing that may change,
  causing the DOCUMENT HEIGHT to change.
 </a>

 <ul class="photos">

  <li ng-repeat="photo in photos" class="photo">

   <img
    bn-lazy-src="{{ photo.src }}"
    width="150"
    height="150"
    alt="Christina Cox"
    />

  </li>

 </ul>



 <!-- Load scripts. -->
 <script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="../../vendor/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js">
 </script>
 <script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="../../vendor/angularjs/angular-1.0.7.min.js">
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">


  // Create an application module for our demo.
  var app = angular.module( "Demo", [] );


  // -------------------------------------------------- //
  // -------------------------------------------------- //


  // I control the root of the application.
  app.controller(
   "AppController",
   function( $scope ) {

    // I flag the visibility of the big box.
    $scope.isBoxVisible = true;

    // Build up a large set of images, all with unique
    // SRC values so that the browser cannot cache them.
    $scope.photos = buildPhotoSet( 200 );


    // ---
    // PUBLIC METHODS.
    // ---


    // I change the SRC values of the existing photo set
    // in order to examine how changes to source will
    // affect rendered / non-rendered images.
    $scope.changeSource = function() {

     var now = ( new Date() ).getTime();

     // Update all SRC attribute to point to "1.jpg".
     for ( var i = 0 ; i < $scope.photos.length ; i++ ) {

      var photo = $scope.photos[ i ];

      photo.src = photo.src.replace( /\d\./i, "1." );

     }

    };


    // I clear the current photo set.
    $scope.clearPhotos = function() {

     $scope.photos = [];

    };


    // I hide the big box, allowing the document to change
    // its dimensions (and possibly show more images than
    // were visible beforehand).
    $scope.hideBox = function() {

     $scope.isBoxVisible = false;

    };


    // I rebuild the entire photo set.
    $scope.rebuildSet = function() {

     $scope.photos = buildPhotoSet( 20 );

    };


    // ---
    // PRIVATE METHODS.
    // ---


    // I return a photo set of the given size. Each photo
    // will have a unique SRC value.
    function buildPhotoSet( size ) {

     var photos = [];
     var now = ( new Date() ).getTime();

     for ( var i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ ) {

      var index = ( ( i % 3 ) + 1 );
      var version = ( now + i );

      photos.push({
       id: ( i + 1 ),
       src: ( "christina-cox-" + index + ".jpg?v=" + version )
      });

     }

     return( photos );

    }

   }
  );


  // -------------------------------------------------- //
  // -------------------------------------------------- //


  // I lazily load the images, when they come into view.
  app.directive(
   "bnLazySrc",
   function( $window, $document ) {


    // I manage all the images that are currently being
    // monitored on the page for lazy loading.
    var lazyLoader = (function() {

     // I maintain a list of images that lazy-loading
     // and have yet to be rendered.
     var images = [];

     // I define the render timer for the lazy loading
     // images to that the DOM-querying (for offsets)
     // is chunked in groups.
     var renderTimer = null;
     var renderDelay = 100;

     // I cache the window element as a jQuery reference.
     var win = $( $window );

     // I cache the document document height so that
     // we can respond to changes in the height due to
     // dynamic content.
     var doc = $document;
     var documentHeight = doc.height();
     var documentTimer = null;
     var documentDelay = 2000;

     // I determine if the window dimension events
     // (ie. resize, scroll) are currenlty being
     // monitored for changes.
     var isWatchingWindow = false;


     // ---
     // PUBLIC METHODS.
     // ---


     // I start monitoring the given image for visibility
     // and then render it when necessary.
     function addImage( image ) {

      images.push( image );

      if ( ! renderTimer ) {

       startRenderTimer();

      }

      if ( ! isWatchingWindow ) {

       startWatchingWindow();

      }

     }


     // I remove the given image from the render queue.
     function removeImage( image ) {

      // Remove the given image from the render queue.
      for ( var i = 0 ; i < images.length ; i++ ) {

       if ( images[ i ] === image ) {

        images.splice( i, 1 );
        break;

       }

      }

      // If removing the given image has cleared the
      // render queue, then we can stop monitoring
      // the window and the image queue.
      if ( ! images.length ) {

       clearRenderTimer();

       stopWatchingWindow();

      }

     }


     // ---
     // PRIVATE METHODS.
     // ---


     // I check the document height to see if it's changed.
     function checkDocumentHeight() {

      // If the render time is currently active, then
      // don't bother getting the document height -
      // it won't actually do anything.
      if ( renderTimer ) {

       return;

      }

      var currentDocumentHeight = doc.height();

      // If the height has not changed, then ignore -
      // no more images could have come into view.
      if ( currentDocumentHeight === documentHeight ) {

       return;

      }

      // Cache the new document height.
      documentHeight = currentDocumentHeight;

      startRenderTimer();

     }


     // I check the lazy-load images that have yet to
     // be rendered.
     function checkImages() {

      // Log here so we can see how often this
      // gets called during page activity.
      console.log( "Checking for visible images..." );

      var visible = [];
      var hidden = [];

      // Determine the window dimensions.
      var windowHeight = win.height();
      var scrollTop = win.scrollTop();

      // Calculate the viewport offsets.
      var topFoldOffset = scrollTop;
      var bottomFoldOffset = ( topFoldOffset + windowHeight );

      // Query the DOM for layout and seperate the
      // images into two different categories: those
      // that are now in the viewport and those that
      // still remain hidden.
      for ( var i = 0 ; i < images.length ; i++ ) {

       var image = images[ i ];

       if ( image.isVisible( topFoldOffset, bottomFoldOffset ) ) {

        visible.push( image );

       } else {

        hidden.push( image );

       }

      }

      // Update the DOM with new image source values.
      for ( var i = 0 ; i < visible.length ; i++ ) {

       visible[ i ].render();

      }

      // Keep the still-hidden images as the new
      // image queue to be monitored.
      images = hidden;

      // Clear the render timer so that it can be set
      // again in response to window changes.
      clearRenderTimer();

      // If we've rendered all the images, then stop
      // monitoring the window for changes.
      if ( ! images.length ) {

       stopWatchingWindow();

      }

     }


     // I clear the render timer so that we can easily
     // check to see if the timer is running.
     function clearRenderTimer() {

      clearTimeout( renderTimer );

      renderTimer = null;

     }


     // I start the render time, allowing more images to
     // be added to the images queue before the render
     // action is executed.
     function startRenderTimer() {

      renderTimer = setTimeout( checkImages, renderDelay );

     }


     // I start watching the window for changes in dimension.
     function startWatchingWindow() {

      isWatchingWindow = true;

      // Listen for window changes.
      win.on( "resize.bnLazySrc", windowChanged );
      win.on( "scroll.bnLazySrc", windowChanged );

      // Set up a timer to watch for document-height changes.
      documentTimer = setInterval( checkDocumentHeight, documentDelay );

     }


     // I stop watching the window for changes in dimension.
     function stopWatchingWindow() {

      isWatchingWindow = false;

      // Stop watching for window changes.
      win.off( "resize.bnLazySrc" );
      win.off( "scroll.bnLazySrc" );

      // Stop watching for document changes.
      clearInterval( documentTimer );

     }


     // I start the render time if the window changes.
     function windowChanged() {

      if ( ! renderTimer ) {

       startRenderTimer();

      }

     }


     // Return the public API.
     return({
      addImage: addImage,
      removeImage: removeImage
     });

    })();


    // ------------------------------------------ //
    // ------------------------------------------ //


    // I represent a single lazy-load image.
    function LazyImage( element ) {

     // I am the interpolated LAZY SRC attribute of
     // the image as reported by AngularJS.
     var source = null;

     // I determine if the image has already been
     // rendered (ie, that it has been exposed to the
     // viewport and the source had been loaded).
     var isRendered = false;

     // I am the cached height of the element. We are
     // going to assume that the image doesn't change
     // height over time.
     var height = null;


     // ---
     // PUBLIC METHODS.
     // ---


     // I determine if the element is above the given
     // fold of the page.
     function isVisible( topFoldOffset, bottomFoldOffset ) {

      // If the element is not visible because it
      // is hidden, don't bother testing it.
      if ( ! element.is( ":visible" ) ) {

       return( false );

      }

      // If the height has not yet been calculated,
      // the cache it for the duration of the page.
      if ( height === null ) {

       height = element.height();

      }

      // Update the dimensions of the element.
      var top = element.offset().top;
      var bottom = ( top + height );

      // Return true if the element is:
      // 1. The top offset is in view.
      // 2. The bottom offset is in view.
      // 3. The element is overlapping the viewport.
      return(
        (
         ( top <= bottomFoldOffset ) &&
         ( top >= topFoldOffset )
        )
       ||
        (
         ( bottom <= bottomFoldOffset ) &&
         ( bottom >= topFoldOffset )
        )
       ||
        (
         ( top <= topFoldOffset ) &&
         ( bottom >= bottomFoldOffset )
        )
      );

     }


     // I move the cached source into the live source.
     function render() {

      isRendered = true;

      renderSource();

     }


     // I set the interpolated source value reported
     // by the directive / AngularJS.
     function setSource( newSource ) {

      source = newSource;

      if ( isRendered ) {

       renderSource();

      }

     }


     // ---
     // PRIVATE METHODS.
     // ---


     // I load the lazy source value into the actual
     // source value of the image element.
     function renderSource() {

      element[ 0 ].src = source;

     }


     // Return the public API.
     return({
      isVisible: isVisible,
      render: render,
      setSource: setSource
     });

    }


    // ------------------------------------------ //
    // ------------------------------------------ //


    // I bind the UI events to the scope.
    function link( $scope, element, attributes ) {

     var lazyImage = new LazyImage( element );

     // Start watching the image for changes in its
     // visibility.
     lazyLoader.addImage( lazyImage );


     // Since the lazy-src will likely need some sort
     // of string interpolation, we don't want to
     attributes.$observe(
      "bnLazySrc",
      function( newSource ) {

       lazyImage.setSource( newSource );

      }
     );


     // When the scope is destroyed, we need to remove
     // the image from the render queue.
     $scope.$on(
      "$destroy",
      function() {

       lazyLoader.removeImage( lazyImage );

      }
     );

    }


    // Return the directive configuration.
    return({
     link: link,
     restrict: "A"
    });

   }
  );

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Reference : [GithubUserContent](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bennadel/6062213/raw/b4c5aae6e96b6115a15f8fb909708814d64d3f3a/lazy-loading-images.htm)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, and great suggestion, it was my fault that I didn't include the requirement that all the photos still load as fast as possible.